# UPDATE INNER JOIN returns 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql

Here is my code

```
UPDATE Remisiones
INNER JOIN temp 
ON `nRemision_tmp` =  `nRemision` 
SET  
    `nLatitudDel` = `nLatitudDel_tmp` ,
    `nLongitudDel` =  `nLongitudDel_tmp` 
WHERE `nRemision_tmp` BETWEEN 3089 AND 4186
```

table `Remisiones` are a 2,400 rows with pk=nRemision int(10) starting with 1

table `temp` are a 1,097 rows with pk=nRemision_tmp int(10) starting with 3089

newbie question from a newbie mysql uiser

any help is welcome

thnaks

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: In your `JOIN ... ON` condition, add the table names to the column names: `ON Remisiones.nRemision = temp.nRemision_tmp`

Comment: If the query runs and updates no rows, then either the `join` or the `where`  are filtering out all rows.  From your description of the tables, I would guess that there are no matches between the tables.

Comment: Then you've got no rows that match the condition. You can test by removing the update and set portions and doing a select on the remaining part: `select * from remisiones inner join temp on nremision_tmp = nremision where nremision_temp between 3089 and 4186` - do you get any rows as a result?

Comment: Ken your sql statement does works and shows 1097 rows as result so the problem is on UPDATE or SET part i used the statement before with no issues maybe logical or syntax error...